# Hmac-sha1 in php

Tags: php, hmacsha1

I've spent several hours reading through many posts already trying to get this to work and am still having issues with it.  I'm trying to use the protectedpdf api which requires a three step process to login and receive an auth token, involving the hmac_sha1 hashing algorithm.

I'm making use of the hmac_hash() function in php so the code is simply:

```
$accessKey = "test";
$dataString = strtolower((string)$clientNonce.(string)$serverNonce.$accesskey);
$clientHash = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha1', $dataString, $accessKey));
```

Where ClientNonce and ServerNonce are uuids like `30df805c-27d6-4df1-b482-48b685cc8f54`

For a sample set of Client and Server Nonces, the built-in php function returns:
`C39B753E50DB06DF3DE8E41C682FA8151B49ECBD` and i get an authentication error in response to the login attempt.

Using the free formatter hmac generator online tool the same input yields:
`7f48c3018c0e53a0b64a60bb7809c7a20a80c9a2`

I would greatly appreciate any help - thanks!!!

Comment: _the_ protectedpdf api? What's that?

Comment: works fine for me; make sure you provide the exact contents of `$dataString` to the online HMAC tool (so lowercase and concatenated in that specific order)

Comment: @VolkerK - protectedpdf is a Digital Rights Management application we're using for publishing a daily financial report.

Comment: You might want to provide a link to its documentation. E.g. `strtolower((string)$clientNonce.(string)$serverNonce.$accesskey);` might be right, might be completely wrong - who knows?

Comment: @HansZ. - thanks - a deeper inspection of the $dataString revealed a typo...so hate it when it turns out to be something stupid like that.  Thanks again for your inputs!!!